# Mysql ANY NOT EQUAL TO subquery not working

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm having a small issue with a query using ANY.

```
Select *, count(*) as m 
from mp_bigrams_raw 
where date_parsed=051213 
and art_source='f' 
and bigram != ANY(select feed_source from mp_feed_sources) 
group by bigram 
order by m DESC 
limit 50;
```

The query runs but it's not excluding the items found in the subquery.

The original query worked when there was only 1 row in the `subquery`.  Once I added more I got an error about more than 1 row.

```
Select *, count(*) as m 
from mp_bigrams_raw 
where date_parsed=051213 
and art_source='f' 
and bigram != (select feed_source from mp_feed_sources) 
group by bigram 
order by m DESC 
limit 50;
```

From there I added ANY and the query runs but seems to ignore the !=.  I'm guessing I'm missing something here.

Thanks

Comment: What datatype is the column `date_parsed`? The condition `date_parsed=05121` looks quite strange. If it's a date the condition is incorrect, if it's a number the leading zero is not relevant and if it's a character column then you'd need to enclose it in single quotes.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name date_parsed is irrelevant. (it's int btw).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use **`NOT IN`**

```
Select *, count(*) as m 
from mp_bigrams_raw 
where date_parsed=051213 
and art_source='f' 
and bigram NOT IN(select feed_source from mp_feed_sources) 
group by bigram 
order by m DESC 
limit 50;
```

Comment: Thanks much. That worked perfectly.  Just out of curiosity why does the != not work?

Comment: @TheEditor **`ANY`** returns `true` (as far as the doc says).

If the **condition** is `true` for any of the entries of the **`subselect`**, so if any of those selected fields is **`!= bigram`** the clause evaluates to **`true`**.

**`NOT IN`** is what you want, so bigram is not in the list of selected values. One of your answer. If it helped you, try considering it as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `left join` with an `is null`:

```
Select r.*, count(*) as m 
from mp_bigrams_raw r
left join mp_feed_sources f on f.feed_source = r.bigram 
where r.date_parsed=051213 
  and r.art_source='f' 
  and f.feed_source is null
group by r.bigram 
order by m DESC 
limit 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition **`ANY`** returns `true` (as far as the doc says), whenever the **condition** is `true` for any of the entries of the **`subselect`**, so if one of those selected fields is **`!= bigram`** the clause evaluates to **`true`**.

**`NOT IN`** is what you want, so bigram is not in the list of selected values.